# При изменении масштаба страницы смещается содержимое сайта

Tags: масштабирование, html, css

Я только-только начал изучать веб-программирование и столкнулся с проблемой, описанной в названии темы.
Вот мой код:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>ПредиСЛОВие</title>
     <style>
           html 
                {
                  height:100%;
                }
           body
                {

                  height:100%;
                  background:url(Image/pr.png);
                  background-size:100%100%;
                  background-attachment:fixed;
                }
           .logo
                 {
                  position:fixed;
                  right:39%;
                 }
           .logo1
                  {
                   position:fixed;
                   bottom:30%;
                   left:10%;
                  }
           .logo2 
                  {
                    position:fixed;
                    bottom:31%;
                    left:41%;
                  }
           .logo3 
                  {
                    position:fixed;
                    bottom:31%;
                    right:10%;
                  }
           .logo4
                  {
                    position:fixed;
                    bottom:23%;
                    left:10%;
                  }

     </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="logo">
                      <a href="prdsl.html">
                                          <img src="Image/pr1.png">
                      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo1">
                       <a href="News.html">
                                          <img src="Image/pr2.png">
                       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo2">
                       <a href="Video.html">
                                           <img src="Image/pr3.png">
                       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo3">
                       <a href="cntk.html">
                                           <img src="Image/pr4.png">
                       </a>
     </div> 
     <div class="logo4">
                       <font size="10" color="white" face="Politica">О ПРОЕКТЕ</font>
     </div>               
</body>
</html>
```

И еще несколько скриншотов, чтобы проиллюстрировать проблему. Скриншоты иллюстрируют состояние страницы до увеличения и уменьшения и после таковых изменений!

Скриншоты:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Исправленный код:

```
   <html>



   <head>
     <title>Slovo - Одесса</title>
     <style>
           html 
                {
                  height:100%;
                }
           body
                {
                  margin:0;
                  height:100%;
                  background:url(Image/pr.png);
                  background-size:100%100%;

                }
       .wrapper 
                { 
                  position: relative;
                  display: block;
                  min-width: 960px;
                  min-height: 700px;

               }
       .logo
             {
              position:absolute;
              top:5px;
              right:990px;
             }
       .logo1
              {
               position:absolute;
               top:645px;
               right:2000px;
              }
       .logo2 
              {
                position:absolute;
                top:655px;
                right:1050px;
              }
       .logo3 
              {
                position:absolute;
                top:634px;
                right:200px;
              }
       .logo4
              {
                position:absolute;
                top:1000px;
                right:2100px;
              }

     </style>
</head>



<body>
     <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="logo">
                      <a href="prdsl.html">
                                          <img src="Image/pr1.png">
                      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo1">
                       <a href="News.html">
                                          <img src="Image/pr2.png">
                       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo2">
                       <a href="Video.html">
                                           <img src="Image/pr3.png">
                       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="logo3">
                       <a href="cntk.html">
                                           <img src="Image/pr4.png">
                       </a>
     </div> 
     <div class="logo4">
                       <font size="10" color="white" face="Politica">О ПРОЕКТЕ</font>
     </div> 
     </div>



</body>



</html>
```

Comment: @АлексейED, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

При использовании `position: fixed;` вы НЕ избежите такой проблемы.
Пара советов:

1) Задайте так называемый "ограничитель" с минимальной высотой и шириной

```
   .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        min-width: 960px;
        min-height: 700px;
   }
```

2) Позиционируйте элементы "абсолютно": `position: absolute;`

Comment: Я все исправил так, как вы говорили. Кроме того, я проценты заменил на пикселе. Дело в том, что теперь кнопки на сайте сдвигаются теперь только в правую сторону при уменьшении масштаба, и в левую - при увеличении. Проблема в том, что они как-то слишком радикально смещаются вправо и влево. При большом увеличении кнопка new вообще исчезает из виду. Не могу понять, как это все исправить. Как обеспечить положительное отображение страницы при любом изменении масштаба страницы, как, например, на этом сайте.